# Помогите! Объединение нескольких .py в .exe

Tags: python, exe

Столкнулся с проблемой. Видел похожий вопрос, и там говорят использовать auto py to exe. Все работает кроме того что он не забирает картинку с логотипом. У меня в папке : основной .py, gui.py , ui.py , logo.png. Все кроме лого есть после работы auto py to exe. Также есть вопрос по поводу того как скрыть открывающийся файл chromedriver.exe, там ничего не показывается кроме загрузки webdrivera.

Comment: А куда он должен забирать лого? Скопируйте сами картинку в каталог с программой.

Comment: Если не затруднит можно привести какой нибудь пример? просто не разу еще не сталкивался с этим.

Comment: Какой пример? Вы копировать файлы не умеете?

Comment: Я использую Visual Studio и естественно картинка лежит в папке проекта.

Comment: У вас картинка лежит в каталоге с .exe?

Comment: Извиняюсь за тупизм. Теперь работает. Хотелось бы конечно чтобы работало без добавления картинки в каталог, но это уже вопрос не к этой теме.Спасибо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504199/how-to-embed-png-images-into-a-single-exe-file-using-py2exe